# Linking Storyboards Without UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uistoryboard

I have an iOS 6 app that I am updating to work with iOS 7 and to make it use storyboards.  I am trying to use multiple storyboards so that I can break my project down into modules for each screen in the app.  So far this has worked out fine but now I need to provide a way to navigate between the various storyboards while still making the work like it did in iOS 6 (but with updated artwork).

I don't use UINavigationController in my existing iOS 6 app and I would prefer not to use it as up to now I have been able to navigate back and forth between XIB's using code on UIButton tap gestures.  The UINavigationController doesn't make it easy to customise how the navigation buttons look from what I have learned so far about it.

I found this very clean way of moving between view controllers that are on different storyboards https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink by passing the name of the storyboard in as an attribute.

But it only seems to work when UINavigationController is used. I get an error "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController" without UINavigationController.

Is there a way to navigate between storyboards by only using the above RBStoryboardlink but without the need for UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance  of  UINavigationController`

This means you are trying to push a view controller to the source while source don't have any navigation controller stack.In that case, you should try to add the instantiated view controller's view as subview to the source view controller's view.

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *viewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
 [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
```

or you modally present, that purely depends on your requirement.

```
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *viewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
 tabBarViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
 [self presentViewController:tabBarViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
```